# Why serverfault.com has gone from the off-topic list?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic, serverfault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regarding the high number of rejected migrations from Stack Overflow to Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150206/regarding-the-high-number-of-rejected-migrations-from-stack-overflow-to-server-f)
>   [Cannot Close as “Belongs on Serverfault”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157471/cannot-close-as-belongs-on-serverfault)

This morning I was trying to flag a question as off-topic to be migrated to serverfault ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698858/lighttpd-configuration?noredirect=1) which has beed migrated to su). But I can't find serverfault in the website list:

[image]

Is there more questions being migrated to sharepoint.se than serverfault? If yes, that's why serverfault isn't in the list anymore?

Comment: Also related: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853/should-server-fault-be-removed-from-stack-overflows-migration-list

Comment: All right, thanks. I was looking for using the [off-topic] tag and nothing popup.

Comment: Because people kept migrating poor quality questions like the one you linked to.  That question, should have been closed.  Please don't migrate crappy questions

Comment: @j0k: Remember the first rule of migrations - Don't Migrate Crap! Now, with that in mind please recalibrate your migration filter so that you only migrate the most exceptionally good questions.

Comment: @lain all right :)