# New Off topic choices for other sites

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

The first page of Off Topic includes migration to SuperUser and ServerFault and then we have the second page.

Several issues

- Shouldn't the other sites just be on one page
- I thought that [ServerFault did not want our migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157472/165773)
- As per other questions could we have an Other site option on the list of sites